# GCP cloud task triggered API throwing 500 and fails 100%

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-tasks

Facing the below issue continuously with one POST request which is triggered from Google Cloud Task. The node application is deployed on Google App Engine. tried even increasing the instances but no luck.

```
Process terminated because the request deadline was exceeded. Please ensure that your HTTP server is listening for requests on 0.0.0.0 and on the port defined by the PORT environment variable. (Error code 123)
```

Any help would be useful. Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: Reading this I think it would be helpful if you could provide further information, like:
What is your app yaml configuration? 
Are you using App Engine Standard or Flex?
Have you checked if it could be affected by the limits? 
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/quotas

Answer (score 1):

I have run into this issue in the past. The question, as posted, doesn't have enough information to narrow down the issue, but here are a few things you can try:

1. **Increase memory size**: It's possible that your instances are running out of memory and failing to start. Try increasing memory size of the instance to see if that helps.
2. **Billing**: Make sure all of your billing information is up to date and the issue isn't related to cost.
3. **Warmups**: Do you have a warmup, liveness check, or readiness check turned on? If so, make sure they are working properly.
4. **Add Logging**: The request has no logs displayed. You should try adding `logging.info(...)` statements in your code to see how far it gets before failing.